# Is it possible to use a powerpoint document as a document template

Tags: content-type, document-template

Just a quick question.I know we can use a word document (.dotx) as a docuent template.But will it be possible to use a powerpoint document?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a library or a Content Type template? Yes, just use a .potx file.

Comment: @Gaurravs please pay attention to your reviews. This is a valid answer.